# What sorting method is this being applied and what is the algorithmic complexity of the method

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I came across the code below for implementing sorting array.

I have applied to a very long array and it was able to do so in under a sec may be 20 millisec or less.

I have been reading about Algorithm complexity and the Big O notation and would like to know:

1. Which is the sorting method (of the existing ones) that is implemented in this code.
2. What is the complexity of the algorithm used here.
3. If you were to improve the algorithm/ code below what would you alter.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
//This program sorts an array
public class SortArray
{
    static void Main(String []args)
    {
        // declaring and initializing the array 
        //int[] arr = new int[] {3,1,4,5,7,2,6,1, 9,11, 7, 2,5,8,4}; 
        
 int[] arr = new int[] {489,491,493,495,497,529,531,533,535,369,507,509,511,513,515,203,205,207,209,211,213,107,109,111,113,115,117,11913,415,417,419,421,423,425,427,15,17,19,21,4,517,519,521,523,525,527,4,39,441,443,445,447,449,451,453,455,457,459,461,537,539,541,543,545,547,1,3,5,7,9,11,13,463,465,467,23,399,401,403,405,407,409,411,499,501,503,505,333,335,337,339,341,343,345,347,65,67,69,71,73,75,77,79,81,83,85,87,89,91,93,95,9,171,173,175,177,179,181,183,185,187,269,271,273,275,277,279,281,283,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47,49,51,53,55,57,59,61,63,133,135,137,139,141,143,145,285,287,289,291,121,123,125,127,129,131,297,299,373,375,377,379,381,383,385,387,389,97,99,101,103,105,147,149,151,153,155,157,159,161,163,165,167,16,391,393,395,397,399,401,403,189,191,193,195,197,199,201,247,249,251,253,255,257,259,261,263,265,267,343,345,347,349,501,503,505,333,335,337,339,341,417,419,421,423,425,561,563,565,567,569,571,573,587,589,591,593,595,597,599,427,429,431,433,301,303,305,307,309,311,313,315,317,319,321,323,325,327,329,331,371,359,361,363,365,367,369,507,509,511,513,515,351,353,355,57,517,519,521,523,525,527,413,415,405,407,409,411,499,435,437,469,471,473,475,477,479,481,483,485,487,545,547,549,551,553,555,575,577,579,581,583,585,557,559,489,491,493,495,497,529,531,533,535,537,539,541,543,215,217,219,221,223,225,227,229,231,233,235,237,239,241,243,245,293,295};
        
  
        int temp; 
          // traverse 0 to array length 
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length ; i++) 
        {
            // traverse i+1 to array length 
            //for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++) 
            for (int j = i+1; j < arr.Length; j++) 
            {
                // compare array element with  
                // all next element 
                if (arr[i] > arr[j]) { 
                    ///Console.WriteLine(i+"i before"+arr[i]); 
                    temp = arr[i]; 
                    arr[i] = arr[j]; 
                    arr[j] = temp; 
                    //Console.WriteLine("i  After"+arr[i]); 
                }
            }
        }           
  
        // print all element of array 
        foreach(int value in arr) 
        { 
            Console.Write(value + " "); 
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: Selection Sort - O(N^2) - there are plent of other options. I was able to find this with a quick Google Search, please try to research something before posting as a question - [Big O Cheat Sheet](https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/)

Comment: When you're learning, this kind of code is fine.  When you're getting things done, you should use [`Array.Sort(arr);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=net-5.0#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_) . Microsoft hires elite computer scientists who really understand complexity and has them spend lots of time making this sort of thing as fast as possible for us mere mortals.

Comment: what if you intend to be part of  Microsoft, Google or Amazon team, they require you to know more than the basics and using array.sort (arrayx)....

Comment: When discussing sorting algorithms, a *"very long array"* is an array with more than one million elements. The array in the question is tiny.

Comment: I ws able to create a very long Array and added time to the code. It took a whooping 40 seconds to do the sorting. Now I can create code with other methods and compare.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3bduh4rrleft7jl/sort.cs?dl=0

Comment: You have two answers so far. Any feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). It's time complexity is O(²). It has nested loops over `i` and `j`, and you can see these produce every possible set of two indices in the range {0,...,-1}, where  is `arr.Length`. The number of pairs is a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), and is equal to:

```
(-1)/2
```

...which is O(²)

If we stick to selection sort, we can still find some improvements.

We can see that the role of the outer loop is to store in `arr[i]` the value that belongs there in the final sorted array, and never touch that entry again. It does so by searching the minimum value in the right part of the array that starts at this index .

Now during that search, which takes place in the inner loop, it keeps swapping lesser values into `arr[i]`. This may happen a few times, as it might find even lesser values as `j` walks to the right. That is a waste of operations, as we would prefer to only perform one swap. And this is possible: instead of swapping immediately, delay this operation. Instead keep track of where the minimum value is *located* (initially at `i`, but this may become some `j` index). Only when the inner loop completes, perform the swap.

There is less important improvement: `i` does not have to get equal to `arr.Length - 1`, as then there are no iterations of the inner loop. So the ending condition for the outer loop can exclude that iteration from happening.

Here is how that looks:

```
for (int i = 0, last = arr.Length - 1; i < last; i++) 
{
    int k = i; // index that has the least value in the range arr[i..n-1] so far
    for (int j = i+1; j < arr.Length; j++) 
    {
        if (arr[k] > arr[j]) { 
            k = j; // don't swap yet -- just track where the minimum is located
        }
    }
    if (k > i) { // now perform the swap
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[k]; 
        arr[k] = temp; 
    }
}
```

A further improvement can be to use the inner loop to not only locate the minimum value, but also the maximum value, and to move the found maximum to the right end of the array. This way both ends of the array get sorted gradually, and the inner loop will shorten twice as fast. Still, the number of comparisons remains the same, and the average number of swaps as well. So the gain is only in the iteration overhead.

Comment: Sir, I tried the code used up there and It did not quite work. It gave a different results. It did not output the entire array.

Comment: Can you link to your implementation where you have it run with an array example?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j6vta2h4shdgzlk/SortArrayNew.cs?dl=0

Comment: If you run this code it will do the sort very well. If you run what's above there it does not run the same way.                                                                                                            dropbox.com/s/3bduh4rrleft7jl/sort.cs?dl=0

Comment: I just saw a typo in my code block. `= arr[i]`. I suppose that's the reason why you got different results. Corrected now.

Comment: Yes, now its working. It runs on average 23-24 secs. My earlier code was doing 40 seconds. So there is a great improvement. You are great in this area. Hope you have a site where you can share the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

This is "Bubble sort" with O(n^2). You can use "Mergesort" or "Quicksort" to improve your algorithm to O(n*log(n)). If you always know the minimum and maximum of your numbers, you can use "Digit sort" or "Radix Sort" with O(n)

See: [Sorting alrogithms in c#](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/170/notes/CSharpHtml/sorting.html)

Comment: It is not bubble sort. See accepted answer.